# Unity: OnTriggerEnter2D does not get called when using Raycast

Tags: collision-detection, unity, raycasting

In a previous [post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/126245/unity-what-type-of-collider-should-i-add-to-a-linerenderer/126289#126289) I talked about creating wires (using Bézier curve) using LineRenderer. I am using a PolygonCollider2D to wrap the wire (see below):

```
GameObject wire = new GameObject ();
LineRenderer lineRenderer = wire.AddComponent<LineRenderer> ();
PolygonCollider2D wireCollider = wire.AddComponent<PolygonCollider2D> ();
```

After drawing the curve and attaching the collider (as described in previous post), I added a new component to my gameObject (a WireController):

```
WireController wireController = wire.AddComponent<WireController> ();
```

The WireController currently has only one method:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    Debug.Log ("I'm hit!");
}
```

I use a Physics2D.Raycast to check if my mouse pointer is at any point interacting with the wire:

```
void CastRay() {
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (ray.origin, ray.direction, 100);

    if (hit) {
        Debug.Log (hit.collider.gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

If I call CastRay() inside a Update() loop, `if (hit)` returns true (if the mouse pointer is over the gameObject, in this case, the wire), but the `OnTriggerEnter2D` method never gets called.

A few observations:

- `collider.isTrigger = true;`
- The `WireController` is attached to the newly created gameObject (it's visible in the Unity editor at runtime)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I might be wrong, but you can't use trigger colliders, you need them to be normal to work with raycasts. (Think about it: there's no enter and exit with a raycast when in a trigger collider)

Comment: That's what I suspected, so I tried setting isTrigger to false, still did not work :(

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood you. Please, read the docs more carefully, because the raycast will never trigger the `OnTriggerEnter` event, because it's when a `Collider` enters it. A `Raycast` doesn't have a proper collider, it's different mechanics.

Comment: I missed that somehow :( Thanks for the help. Then I guess I can call a method whenever I have a hit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Helper class responsible for checking if the wire is cut, that contains the following method:

```
public delegate void CallbackAction();

public static void CheckIfWireIsCut(Camera camera, string tag, CallbackAction callback) {
    if (!Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
        return;
    }

    Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (ray.origin, ray.direction, 100);

    if (hit && hit.collider.gameObject.tag.Equals(tag)) {
        callback ();
    }
}
```

In the WireController code, I created a callback method and in the Update() loop I check if the wire is cut:

```
void Update () {
    GameHelper.CheckIfWireIsCut (Camera.main, gameObject.tag, CutWire);
}

public void CutWire() {
    Debug.Log ("Cut me!");
}
```

This works for my use case. Hope it helps other people with similar issues.