# How to add Collider to a Line Renderer in unity?

Tags: unity, collider

I have created a semicircle using a line renderer, I need to add a collider to this so whenever enemy objects hit this they get destroyed, how do I do this.
Current Code

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CreateCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    public float radius;
    void Start()

    {
        int segments =60;
        int pointCount = segments+1;

        Vector3[] points = new Vector3[pointCount];

        LineRenderer line = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        line.positionCount = pointCount; //line.SetVertexCount(pointCount);

        for(int i=0;i<pointCount;i++)
        {
            float Deg = (i*60 / segments);
            float Rad = Mathf.Deg2Rad *Deg;

            points[i] = new Vector3 ( Mathf.Sin(Rad) * radius,Mathf.Cos(Rad)*radius,0);
            // Debug.Log(" Point: "+i+" Deg: "+Deg+" Rad: "+Rad+" Vector 3:"+points[i]);
        }
        line.SetPositions(points);

        Mesh lineMesh = new Mesh();
        line.BakeMesh(lineMesh,Camera.main,true);

        MeshCollider lineCollider = line.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();

    }

    void OnColliderEnter(Collider col){
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }

}
```
````

Comment: We have some [existing Q&A showing a couple of options you can try](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/126245/39518). If the approaches described there don't work for your specific needs, or if you run into trouble implementing them, please edit your question to clarify what you need to solve and we can re-open it for new answers.

Comment: As you can see in my question I am not generating my line using bezier points its based on a simple angle calculation and I would like to keep it simple as is.

Comment: That's fine, the collider won't know or care whether your points are from a Bézier curve, stock market prices, or simply hand-picked positions. So the solutions of using polygon or edge colliders as described at the link will work just fine.